# Dynamic kml and CGI

Tags: cgi, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a problem that I need help to solve involving kml files. Let me start out by saying that I am not a programmer and never intended to try to be one when I started the current project. Because the original programmer took the previously developed code and left to go make money with it, I am stuck with trying to rewrite programs, finish buiding the website ect... all of which I had not a clue of how to do. If not for the fact that I am tenatious in regards of teaching myself what I don't know in order to get things done, the project would have been dead! I'm still not sure if I'm beating a dead horse here, but this is my last attempt to try to get this done.

I have developed a website and setup a multiplayer server dedicated to the use of ships in FSX, Microsoft's Flight Simulator program. Still working on the website http://www.fsnavnet.com and I am useing third party server software for the multiplayer aspect. What I need to do in order to move forward with everything is to create a "Fleet Tracker" page on the website using Google Earth Plugin. The code for the webpage and plugin are done.

I'm trying to incorporate a third party program called FSX Google Earth Tracker that was developed using C# that actually tracks individual FSX aircraft / boats ect..using Google Earth. Pretty cool!! The program has a feature that allows you to create a kml file. I have taken that kml, placed in on the website, wrote the webpage for it and tweaked the kml and finaly got it to work LOCALY, meaning that I can only see aircraft / boat traffic on the website through the machine that has Flight Simulator and FSX Google Earth Tracker installed on it. (I have two computers running, both with virtual machines installed in order to develop and test things for the website and FSX Google Earth Tracker.)

Here is the kml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<LookAt>
        <longitude>-100.6738312112837</longitude>
        <latitude>36.41206190789826</latitude>
        <altitude>0</altitude>
        <heading>0</heading>
        <tilt>0</tilt>
        <range>9475744.521612534</range>
        <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
</LookAt>
    <Folder>
        <name>User Aircraft</name>
        <open>1</open>
<NetworkLink>
        <name>Current Position</name>
<Link>
        <name>Current Position</name>
        <href>http://localhost:9016/fsxu.kml</href>
        <refreshMode>onExpire</refreshMode>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>          
<NetworkLink>
        <name>Course Prediction</name>
<Link>
        <name>Course Prediction</name>
        <href>http://localhost:9016/fsxpre.kml</href>
        <refreshMode>onExpire</refreshMode>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>

    </Folder>
    <Folder>
        <name>AI Objects</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <NetworkLink>
        <name>Aircrafts</name>
<Link>
        <name>Aircrafts</name>
        <href>http://localhost:9016/fsxaip.kml</href>
        <refreshMode>onExpire</refreshMode>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>
<NetworkLink>
        <name>Helicopters</name>
<Link>
        <name>Helicopters</name>
        <href>http://localhost:9016/fsxaih.kml</href>
        <refreshMode>onExpire</refreshMode>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>

<NetworkLink>
        <name>Boats</name>
<Link>
        <name>Boats</name>
        <href>http://localhost:9016/fsxaib.kml</href>
        <refreshMode>onExpire</refreshMode>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>


    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I've been doing research on the web trying to find out how to make the kml dynamic on the webpage. The site IS broadcasting (if I could use that term) the kml in terms of of the "look at" parameters I've writtne into it, as you can see the globe tilt, turn and adjust zoom when you first open that page, but no "Flight Sim" traffic is present, I found pages on the web talking about using Python CGI, to make kml files dynamic, but I can get Python to work with on my WAMP test server, and if I did I don't have a clue of how to write a .py script to get the kml to do what I need it to do. I've been trying for week researching this thing with no luck.

So my question here is: What are the alternatives if any, to getting the kml to work dynamicaly on the website to display what I'm trying to get it to display? I've seen other Flight Simulator based websites that have done what I am trying to do using Google Maps.( http://www.itsyourplane.com/startup.asp?p=/html/iyptracker.asp ) I've tried contacting those developers to get a bead on how they did it, but no one is talking!

If I can't get this resolved I am left with no other choice than to shut down the project, which I would hate to do after all of the time and effort I've put into it. Any help / guidance would be greatlly appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your kml is referencing localhost:

```
http://localhost:9016/fsxu.kml
```

That will not be accessible over the web.  You need to change those URLs to be for the public name of your webserver (so probably something like:

```
http://www.fsnavnet.com/kml/fsxu.kml
```

and you will need to [verify that your server is 
configured to serve kml files](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server))